# FOREIGN KEY constraint error on insert even though entry already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've created two tables, Customers and Records. Records has a foreign key constraint on customerID. When I try inserting a record to a customer that already exists, it gives me this error:

```
  Message (The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_REC_cstmr_int_id". The conflict occurred in database "Omitted", table "dbo.CST_NEW_CUSTOMER", column 'cstmr_int_id'.)
```

Here is the insert code:

```
INSERT INTO [Omitted].[dbo].[REC_NEW_RECORDS]
       ([cstmr_int_id]
       ,[xml_tx]
VALUES
       (10
       ,'<test>test</test>'
GO
```

Most of the related questions I have found on here talked about inserting in the wrong order, but I can select the customer with id 10. Any pointers would be appreciated.

edit 1: This returns one customer

```
SELECT [cstmr_int_id]
   FROM [Omitted].[dbo].[CST_NEW_CUSTOMER] WHERE cstmr_int_id =10
```

edit 2: Here is the create script for the records table

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[REC_NEW_RECORDS](
[rec_int_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
[cstmr_int_id] [int] NOT NULL,
[xml_tx] [varchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [REC_PK_rec_int_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[rec_int_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REC_NEW_RECORDS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_REC_cstmr_int_id] FOREIGN KEY([cstmr_int_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CST_NEW_CUSTOMER] ([cstmr_int_id])
GO
```

Comment: You're saying that `dbo.cst_new_customer` has a record of `10` and SQL Server is drunk?

Comment: It has 20 customers in it, one of which has id 10

Comment: I would suggest taking another close look at the code to that FK.   You should only get that error if there is no record in the PK table with an ID of 10.  Make sure the FK is really constructed the way you think it is, and that the ID in the parent table really exists.

Comment: Could you please go in SSMS right click on tables and 'Script Table as ' --> 'Create to' and paste the script here after some masking. Maybe there is something that you are missing

Comment: But your error indicates there is a FK relationship between `dbo.CST_NEW_CUSTOMER` and `dbo.REC_NEW_RECORDS` on the cstmr_int_id column. If you wrote `SELECT * FROM dbo.CST_NEW_CUSTOMER C WHERE C.cstmr_int_id = 10` do you get results?

Comment: What is `TCO514`? That isn't mentioned elsewhere in the Q.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to rename it. TCO didnt seem friendly

Comment: `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REC_NEW_RECORDS]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_REC_cstmr_int_id] FOREIGN KEY([cstmr_int_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CST_NEW_CUSTOMER] ([cstmr_int_id])` <- That tells you everything you need to know. Before a row can go in `REC_NEW_RECORDS`, the specified cstmr_int_id **must** already exist in `CST_NEW_CUSTOMER`. Since your constraint specified WITH CHECK, that means it's valid (if you disable it, it's marked as untrusted and will allow you to violate RI). This is Relational Integrity working as intended.

Comment: Any trigger on `REC_NEW_RECORDS` that's perhaps trying to add more rows to the table, which results in the FK violation?

Comment: @billinkc The cstmr_int_id already exists in CST_NEW_CUSTOMER

Comment: Which is more probable - that you have discovered an elementary bug with SQL Server or that you something wrong with your code?

Comment: @AndriyM I dont believe so. How would I check that?

Comment: @billinkc SELECT * FROM dbo.CST_NEW_CUSTOMER C WHERE C.cstmr_int_id = 10 returns a customer. Im aware that this is probably an error in my code, but its not the simple one you pointed me to.

Comment: Try putting your `INSERT` into a `TRY/CATCH` block and put the `SELECT` statement in the `CATCH` section. I'd also try using a variable for the insert value as well as the select where equality value. If there are any transactional issues this should get you the correct values within the [dbo].[CST_NEW_CUSTOMER] table for the scope of the insert.

Comment: Also, is the cstmr_int_id column in dbo.CST_NEW_CUSTOMER an `INT`? If it is a different datatype you could be getting equality issues for a number of reasons. This seems like a stupid suggestion, but your question defies logic so need to start looking at the basics.

Comment: As you are scrubbing your code to make it more friendly to this audience, perhaps in your cleaning you've managed to fix whatever is broken. Having lived with table names of `TCO514` and the like, it's an easy thing to do

Comment: @billinkc's supposition about name mix-up seems to me more plausible than a trigger doing odd things, but just to be on the safe side, this is how you can see if there are any active triggers on `dbo.REC_NEW_RECORDS`: `SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.REC_NEW_RECORDS') AND is_disabled = 0;`. And this is how you can inspect a trigger's body: `EXEC sp_helptext 'your trigger name';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the same connection for all the queries/statements above?

The problem *might* just be related to an uncommitted transaction.

Comment: How would I check this?

Comment: `SELECT er.session_id, er.open_transaction_count FROM sys.dm_exec_requests er Where open_transaction_count > 0`

Comment: It was related to an uncommitted transaction. Thanks to Love2Learn as well!

Comment: @Bishop - Foreign key lookups don't read uncommitted data. An uncommitted transaction would have caused blocking not a spurious error.

Comment: I'm not sure what caused, and what fixed it then. There was another guy working on the same db while I was. Perhaps it was related to that.

Comment: On a related note, when using SQLAlchemy just making sure to issue a flush if adding two or more objects related by a foreignkey constraint.

Answer (score 5):

That value does not exist in the referenced table. Here's a scenario that does not have `10` in your referenced table:

**Set up**

```
create table cst_new_customer (
  cstmr_int_id int not null primary key);

insert into cst_new_customer (cstmr_int_id) values (9), (11);

create table rec_new_records (
  cstmr_int_id int not null primary key,
  xml_tx varchar(50));

alter table rec_new_records add constraint fk_rec_cstmr_int_id
foreign key (cstmr_int_id) references cst_new_customer (cstmr_int_id);
```

**Test 1**

```
insert into rec_new_records values (10, 'test');
```

**Result**

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_rec_cstmr_int_id". The conflict occurred in database "db_3_055da", table "dbo.cst_new_customer", column 'cstmr_int_id'.:

**Test 2**

```
insert into rec_new_records values (11, 'test');
```

**Result**

```
| CSTMR_INT_ID | XML_TX |
|--------------|--------|
|           11 |   test |
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2435b/1)

Comment: The customer with id 10 exists in the db though

Comment: Well, it doesn't. What's the result of `SELECT * FROM dbo.CST_NEW_CUSTOMER C WHERE C.cstmr_int_id = 10`?

Comment: Can you try dropping the constraint and re-adding it?

Answer (score 0):

One possible scenario for this problem that I experienced today was that I had two foreign key constraints. I only inserted one of them in the referenced table but I was unaware of the second foreign key constraint that was not inserted.